# react-redux architecture handle error locally and globally

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-redux

I have an app that has a wide range of client validations and a lot of ajax requests.

I am using "axios" for the ajax calls, and I know how I can catch all errors like: 401, 403, 404 etc...

In case I have that kind of error I would simply show a toast with the error.

BUT

I want to display an error on a specific form the user is submitting, and if I handle the error locally on that form so there is no reason to show the global warning.

Any ideas on how to implement it?

Comment: Global warning is a myth.

Comment: @DaveNewton :D well need a general catch to show a toaster with the error unless I handle it locally :/

Comment: @DaveNewton... you funny guy, you... xp